# Read from one database and write to another php/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm learning Laravel and would know howto read data from a db and write it automatically to a second db.

First I read from db1 and it works:

```
$paciente_q = Pacientes::on('db1')->find($id);
```

Then I wish to move the data to an identical table on db2 (assigned in the configuration)

```
Pacientes::create($paciente_q);
```

The error is that I pass an object and "::create" wants an array. I converted it to an array but didn't work. The only option that I can find is to create an array with the data and then make the ::create. But I think that there should be an easier way. I'm talking about 10 columns.

What could I do if we talk about hundreds of columns?

Comment: Why did converting to an array not work? Did you get an error?

Comment: You just want to copy the tables? Use SQL not Eloquent. Or show the reason for using Eloquent.

Comment: I need to read data from db1 and if this data does not exists in db2, then the app should write it to the db2. I work with two db's. One with only read perms, and the second where we can write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach didn't work probably because by default [mass assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment) is prevented for security reasons; you need to manually set the model's fields that are mass assignable in the `fillable` property of the model (that should be an array) - if you do not care about that security or are sure that you'll never directly mass-assign user input to your models you can make all the fields mass assignable by setting the `guarded` property of the model to an empty array.

Once that's done, your code is mostly correct, just convert the model to an array and don't forget to select the second database when creating the model, like so :

```
// the model to insert, converted to an array - get() would also work but first() ensures we get only one record even if the primary key is messed up and there are multiple values with the same ID
$paciente_q = Pacientes::on("db1")->find($id)->first()->toArray();

// create the same model on the second database
Pacientes::on("db2")->create($paciente_q);
```

Now, if you want to do it occasionally for a few rows then the above approach is suitable, otherwise you may look at [bulk insertion](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#inserts), here's an example for copying the entire table from your first database to the second one :

```
// an array with all the rows
$patients = Pacientes::on("db1")->all()->toArray();

// get the model's table name
$table = with(new Pacientes)->getTable(); 

// bulk insert all these rows into the second database
DB::connection("db2")->table($table)->insert($patients);
```

Note that here we're not using Eloquent for inserting them, so we must first get the table's name from an instance of the model; if the table's name on the second database is different from the first then adjust the `$table` variable accordingly.

Comment: Tried your first solution and got error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/bg-dental/app/controllers/PresupuestosController.php on line 47 and defined...  
I don't specify the second db beacause it is the standrad one in the config.

Comment: Got this:  
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toArray()"

Comment: That worked to make the array! Thanks!
But I can't insert data. I get the array  with the timestamps too. And this two columns should't be filled with data from other table. They should have the actual date when i create the new row in db2. So, i think that i must select each column from all without the timestamps and id columns to get the data in db2... I could put the timestamps to false in the model but i need the "created at" and "updated_at" timestamps. I will declare a search scope in the model file to avoid write it every time. Do you think is a good way to resolv?

Comment: Mysql.log:  
'79 Prepare insert into `pacientes` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?)  
141118  9:57:58    79 Execute insert into `pacientes` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('2014-11-18 08:57:57', '2014-11-18 08:57:57')'

Comment: @BanMajstrovic what about setting the timestamp columns (`updated_at`, etc) in the `guarded` array of the model to prevent their mass assignment while allowing everything else ?

Comment: I thought that the guarded and fillable arrays were only for mass asignment generated by user input and not by queries from a controller. I tried it but didn work...  I tried also:  
`$paciente_q = Pacientes::on('db1')->where('numerohistoria',$numerohistoria)->get(array('numerohistoria','nombre','apellido1'))->toArray();  
    var_dump($paciente_q);  
    Pacientes::create($paciente_q);`
 Got an array with the correct data.  But in the mysql.log:  
`Execute insert into `pacientes` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('2014-11-18 09:27:30', '2014-11-18 09:27:30')`

Comment: @BanMajstrovic that's indeed the purpose of these attributes, but Eloquent doesn't care from where the values come from, not that it can know for sure (an array created manually and one from `Input::all()` looks the same to Eloquent). I don't understand, you said you don't want to keep the old timestamps from the row in `db1`, but it looks like the timestamps you get now are fresh.

Comment: I don't want the timestamps from db1 on db2. I need new oneas. But it seems that eloquent creates a row with the new timestamps and with no data...

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change the get() to first() because we were searching for one item. I read wrong the first solution from @André... sorry! Should learn to read instead of Laravel!

```
$paciente_q = Pacientes::on('db1')->where('numerohistoria',$numerohistoria)->first()->toArray();

    Pacientes::create($paciente_q);
```

Now it works!! Thanks to all and specially to @André !